# Internet Explorer WebDriver hangs for an hour during CreateSession API Call

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-driver

Internet Explorer Driver hangs for an hour during CreateSession Call. It hangs for an hour to find window handle for Internet Explorer Server and this issues happens intermittently. Has anyone experienced a similar issue ?

InternetExplorerDriver Version: 64-bit, 3.141.59

Microsoft Windows Server 2019: 64 bit

```
BrowserFactory::LaunchBrowserUsingIELaunchURL
D 2020-05-15 03:36:53:582 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(250) Starting IE using the IELaunchURL API
D 2020-05-15 03:36:54:386 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(204) IE launched successfully with process ID 4888
D 2020-05-15 03:36:54:386 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(210) Process with ID 4888 is executing iexplore.exe
T 2020-05-15 03:36:54:386 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(368) Entering BrowserFactory::AttachToBrowser
D 2020-05-15 03:36:54:386 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(378) Using Active Accessibility to find IWebBrowser2 interface
T 2020-05-15 03:36:54:386 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(427) Entering BrowserFactory::AttachToBrowserUsingActiveAccessibility
D 2020-05-15 04:36:59:140 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(447) Found window handle 0000000000040298 for window with class 'Internet Explorer_Server' belonging to process with id 4888
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:140 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(332) Entering BrowserFactory::GetDocumentFromWindowHandle
D 2020-05-15 04:36:59:611 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(399) Ignoring zoom setting: 0
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:611 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(591) Entering BrowserFactory::GetBrowserZoomLevel
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:636 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(631) Entering BrowserFactory::GetZoomLevel
D 2020-05-15 04:36:59:671 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\BrowserFactory.cpp(711) Browser zoom level is 100%
I 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\IECommandExecutor.cpp(1366) Persistent hovering set to: 1
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\ProxyManager.cpp(103) ProxyManager::SetProxySettings
D 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\ProxyManager.cpp(119) Using existing system proxy settings.
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\DocumentHost.cpp(36) Entering DocumentHost::DocumentHost
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\CookieManager.cpp(48) Entering CookieManager::Initialize
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\Browser.cpp(38) Entering Browser::Browser
T 2020-05-15 04:36:59:672 C:\Projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\Browser.cpp(383) Entering Browser::AttachEvents
```

Comment: If possible, then can you please try to provide any sample code to reproduce this issue to see the result? It will be helpful for us to understand the issue in a better way. Did you try to use the latest IE driver to see whether it helps to fix this issue or not?

Comment: I have the same problem on a jenkins win node. any progress or idea what is going on?